# Filtering a multicolumn groupby result in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Using Pandas, how would I filter my Dataframe so that only days where the total of transactions for the day > N show?

```
import pandas as pd
data = [
    ["2017-01-01 00:00:01.012345", 'Jen', 1.01],
    ["2017-01-01 01:00:00.012345", 'Joe', 3.02],
    ["2017-02-01 00:00:00.012345", 'Jen', 2.02],
    ["2017-02-01 02:00:00.012345", 'Joe', 0.02],
    ["2017-03-01 03:00:00.012345", 'Jen', 3.02],
    ["2017-03-01 04:00:00.012345", 'Joe', 4.04],
    ["2017-03-01 05:00:01.012345", 'Jen', 5.01]]
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'trx_time': list(zip(*data))[0],
    'agent': list(zip(*data))[1],
    'trx_amount': list(zip(*data))[2]})
df['day'] = df['trx_time'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x).date())
grouped = df.groupby(['day', 'agent'])
by_day_df = grouped.aggregate('sum')\
    .rename(columns = lambda x: 'day_tl_' + x)\
    .join(pd.DataFrame(grouped.size(), columns=['trx_count']))
print (by_day_df)
```

Output:

```
day        agent                              
2017-01-01 Jen                 1.01          1
           Joe                 3.02          1
2017-02-01 Jen                 2.02          1
           Joe                 0.02          1
2017-03-01 Jen                 8.03          2
           Joe                 4.04          1
```

So after filtering I don't want either of the rows for 2017-02-01 to show, as the total for the day < 3.

Can this be done with .filter()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Important part is to `groupby` the first level of the index and take the sum of the column `day_tl_trx_amount`
- Then we need to filter the grouped and summed data by only those days whose sum was greater than or equal to `3`
- Finally, we use these days to filter the first dataframe

---

***find the days with sum >= 3***

```
idx = by_day_df.groupby(level='day')[['day_tl_trx_amount']].sum() \
    .query('day_tl_trx_amount >= 3').index.tolist()
```

***filter first dataframe***

```
by_day_df.loc[idx]

                  day_tl_trx_amount  trx_count
day        agent                              
2017-01-01 Jen                 1.01          1
           Joe                 3.02          1
2017-03-01 Jen                 8.03          2
           Joe                 4.04          1
```

---

***A bit more elegantly with `unstack` and `sum`***
My preferred solution

```
s = by_day_df.unstack().day_tl_trx_amount.sum(1).ge(3)
by_day_df.loc[s.index[s].tolist()]

                  day_tl_trx_amount  trx_count
day        agent                              
2017-01-01 Jen                 1.01          1
           Joe                 3.02          1
2017-03-01 Jen                 8.03          2
           Joe                 4.04          1
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can remove rows by [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by first level of index and aggregate `sum`, last [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) these rows:

```
df1 = by_day_df.groupby(level=0)['day_tl_trx_amount'].sum()
idx = df1[df1 < 3].index
print (idx)
Index([2017-02-01], dtype='object', name='day')

print (by_day_df.drop(idx, level=0))
                  day_tl_trx_amount  trx_count
day        agent                              
2017-01-01 Jen                 1.01          1
           Joe                 3.02          1
2017-03-01 Jen                 8.03          2
           Joe                 4.04          1
```

Similar solution with selecting dates what need by `loc`:

```
df1 = by_day_df.groupby(level=0)['day_tl_trx_amount'].sum()
print (df1)
day
2017-01-01     4.03
2017-02-01     2.04
2017-03-01    12.07
Name: day_tl_trx_amount, dtype: float64

idx = df1[df1 >= 3].index.tolist()
print (idx)
[datetime.date(2017, 1, 1), datetime.date(2017, 3, 1)]

print (by_day_df.loc[idx])
                  day_tl_trx_amount  trx_count
day        agent                              
2017-01-01 Jen                 1.01          1
           Joe                 3.02          1
2017-03-01 Jen                 8.03          2
           Joe                 4.04          1
```

Also some improvement of your code, mainly [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) for creating `DataFrame` from `Series`:

```
#vectorized to_datetime and then dt.date
df['day'] = pd.to_datetime(df['trx_time']).dt.date

grouped = df.groupby(['day', 'agent'])
by_day_df = grouped.trx_amount.sum().to_frame() \
                   .rename(columns = lambda x: 'day_tl_' + x)\
                   .join(grouped.size().to_frame('trx_count'))
print (by_day_df)
  agent  trx_amount                    trx_time
0   Jen        1.01  2017-01-01 00:00:01.012345
1   Joe        3.02  2017-01-01 01:00:00.012345
2   Jen        2.02  2017-02-01 00:00:00.012345
3   Joe        0.02  2017-02-01 02:00:00.012345
4   Jen        3.02  2017-03-01 03:00:00.012345
5   Joe        4.04  2017-03-01 04:00:00.012345
6   Jen        5.01  2017-03-01 05:00:01.012345
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to solve it using mask:

```
by_day_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
mask=by_day_df.groupby('day')['day_tl_trx_amount'].sum()>3
by_day_df.set_index('day',inplace=True)
by_day_df=by_day_df[mask]
by_day_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
by_day_df.set_index(['day','agent'],inplace=True)
```